# project Euler #2 in java

Tags: java, fibonacci

Can anyone take a look at my java code, and telling me how to fix my code. The question is below. I would really appreciate any help :)

```
public class problem
{
    public static void main (String args []){
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        problem();
    }

    public static int problem(){

        int c = a + b;
        if (c>10){
            System.out.println(c);
            return c;
        }
        int a = b;
        int b = c;
        problem();
    }
}
```

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> `1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...`
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

Comment: you didn't declare youvariables outside of your main method

Comment: Given that you are not very experienced at Java, I'd like to point out that Java is not the best tool for solving Project Euler problems, and solving Project Euler problems is not the best way to learn Java. If your goal is to have fun with programming problems, use Python or Ruby. If your goal is to learn Java, a more practical project might be a better approach.

Comment: Your class is also the same name as your method (in case and name), and `void main()` usually isn't in a class?

Comment: @EricWilson can you explain why Java is not good at solving P.E. problems? I use both C# and java..however I use NUnit/JUnit to help me step by step to solve the problems. Granted it probably takes longer to solve the problem, but I don't see it as being a bad tool. Could you please explain?

Comment: @RobertSnyder That's one way to do it, using unit tests is a little better than working with a `main` method, but even better is using a language with a REPL for even faster feedback. As a professional Java programmer, I just prefer using more lightweight tools for smaller problems.

Answer (score 1):

A few problems.  `a` and `b` should be static member variables if you want all of your methods to have access to it.  `problem()` is returning an int, but only sometimes.  This doesn't really need to return anything so I made it void.

This version will print out the first Fibonacci number greater then 10 and then stop, but you want the first one greater then 4 million, and you want the sum of the numbers.  So we need to keep track of that.

Also your starting values was 0 1 Fibonacci sequence should start and 1 and 2.

And last we only want to sum up the even numbers, we can do this by checking if the reminder is 0 when divided by two.

```
public class problem
{
    private static int a = 0;
    private static int b = 0;
    private static int sum = 0;

    public static void main (String args []){
        a = 1;    
        b = 2;
        problem();
        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
    }

    public static void problem(){
        if (b % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + b;
        }

        int c = a + b;
        if (c>=4000000)
        {
            return;
        }

        a = b;
        b = c;
        problem();
    }
}
```